# Django multisite

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

What's the easiest way to make apps specific to a subdomain. The project I'm working on for a client requires to have a subdomain were users can talk about the site in general same as meta on stack overflow. For example if a main django site is hosted on example.com I would like to have another app that is specific to meta.example.com or can I use a single app together with django.contrib.sites to accomplish this? But my problem with this route is:

I have the following fields
on example.com:

```
title
body
category (specific to example.com)
tags
```

on meta.example.com

```
same fields but category (specific to meta.example.com)
```

The content need to be edited from one admin page.

Comment: You need two different applications, or just two different ModelForms pointing to the same model, but one of them excluding the `category` field.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a middleware that will check on what subdomain u are, and populate categories